# how to avoid when the data is an empty array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "id": 43,
    "dataEvento": "2022-09-01T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "dataInvio": null,
    "idComunicazioneAssociata": null,
    "certificatoMedico": []
}
```

I'm using a condition on template but doens't work.

```
            <ng-container *ngIf="segnalazione.certificatoMedico !== []">
             .............
            </ng-container>
```

I want to show this `ng-container` only when I have data in `certificatoMedico`

Any ideas please how to do this? Because that's not how it works for me.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `*ngIf="segnalazione.certificatoMedico.length` and in javascript  `[] === []` always evalutes to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length !

`*ngIf="segnalazione.certificatoMedico.length !== 0"`

Answer (score 1):

Check the length, but do it the smart way :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!segnalazione?.certificatoMedico?.length">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, javascript is a weird language, use .length to check if an array is empty
`<ng-container *ngIf="segnalazione.certificatoMedico.length > 0">`

There is no simple way to compare arrays https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-compare-two-javascrpt-arrays.html

`!==` is checking if it's the same object